RStudio Viewer slower than browser window
I'm working on a package for interactive visualization in R using htmlwidgets and code I've written in TypeScript/JavaScript.
This works fairly well but I've noticed that the apps are a bit laggy in the RStudio Viewer compared to the browser (even if I launch it from RStudio, by clicking the button on the top right of the Viewer panel). The issue doesn't seem to be related to the dataset size & is the most noticeable with smaller datasets (which run snappy in the browser). With larger datasets (~50k cases) the rendering lag swamps out the difference.
Here's a link to my repo, it's got instructions on how to install the package/run an example: https://github.com/bartonicek/plotscape/tree/master/packages/plotscaper

I don't know that I would expect it to be faster, and being a little slower does not surprise me at all, Posit doesn't make their viewer to be as fast as "professional" web browsers. I suspect you might get better support from the Posit Community, though it's certainly possible you may get help here. If it's significant, you may need to create a new issue, though I suspect you'll need to provide a self-contained min-reprex to better help getting resolution faster.

Thanks, yeah I've posted on posit community two days ago but got no responses so far. I don't really know RStudio internals so any information you can provide could be helpful, I thought the viewer was just an embedded browser.

Also, I don't see this issue with e.g. plotly, that one is about the same speed in the viewer as in the browser, regardless of data size.

I think it is "just" an embedded browser, but ... it's not embedded Chrome or Firefox. I expect that it is generally pretty featureful, but I would not expect it to perfectly replicate everything that a full-time web-browser will do. I didn't see your post on PositComm, thanks. Okay, we'll take another look.

Thank you, that's very helpful. Since you mentioned it, I have noticed some differences from modern broswers - e.g. I found I have to export the package as an iife, ecmascript import statements don't seem to work.
